# mysql replication stops without errors

Tags: mysql, debian, replication

I have this issue with master to master replication setup. Replication stops without errors, but when I make: slave stop; slave start; it is working again.

```
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.41, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using 

readline 6.2

root@localhost:mysqld.sock:localhost/(none)> show slave status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 62.xx.222.99
                  Master_User: slave
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.002022
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 59142342
               Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.002651
                Relay_Log_Pos: 2192375
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.002022
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: edata
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: edata.c,edata.odetails,edata.e,edata.o,edata.mailing
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 59142342
              Relay_Log_Space: 10458329
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 2
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Generally replication works fine, but sometimes it stops and I don't see any errors.

Comment: Something *must* happen. Is the MySQL serevr being restarted and you don't have replication configured to start automatically? Show the slave status when it's stopped (add it to the question, don't waste time trying to add it as a comment).

Comment: xtrabackup? it stops replication thread IIRC

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer - server runs without restarts and I don't use xtrabackup - I saw that when I change some settings in main router like external ip aliases then replication stops.